# Damage replacement plan / Insurance for Mac Book Pro?

Tags: warranty, repair

I used to own a Dell with a pretty beefy replacement plan.  When I bought my MBP, I asked if there was any similar coverage and the "genius" said no.  I search around online and found a company called [Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/Default.aspx), but it would be hard for me to believe that this would be the only company around doing this.

Does anyone own insurance like what Dell offers for their Mac?  Has anyone ever destroyed their computer and got a replacement?

Comment: Isn't apple care just that?

Comment: Apple care only extends the warranty, if you drop your computer and it doesn't turn on... you are up the creek =/

Comment: The same insurance plans that cover any sort of [personal products](http://www.statefarm.com/insurance/other/personal.asp) will likely cover technology if you understand the riders, deductibles and whether you have to report purchases to them within a period. Also some credit cards have limited loss and damage clauses, but you might be better off insuring your property explicitly through a company you select for just that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not offer any insurance like that with Applecare. I think Dell only offers it because replacing a piece of equipment is ultimately really cheap for them, but Apple doesn't play Dell's game (and that is probably part of the reason why you purchased an Apple product).

Going by the fact that you are in the USA, I think this would depend on the type of damages for which you are seeking insurance, which you don't specify in your question. Renter's or home insurance would protect against theft from your home (rent or own, respectively). Damage incurred while being on the road would probably fall under some kind of business insurance, though I'd imagine you would pay a pretty hefty penny for that level of care no matter who you call.

I think your best course action would be to call your insurance company and see what they have to offer that best suits your particular needs.

Comment: I do have renter's insurance, so theft from my home would be covered.  I don't think that renter's insurance would cover me if I drop it in my house.  You said "call my insurance company," but I don't really have a company beside my renters and auto insurance.  Have you insured your Apple in some way?

Comment: Apple also are careful to not play favorites when they refer you to someone like a repair shop, insurance claim - the "genius" you asked probably heard you asking for a recommendation and not whether you people would sell you a policy.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: I have not insured my Macs, but if I were running some kind of business where I was on the road all the time, then I definitely would (call me a reckless fool). I'll bet your insurance company has other packages as well since they have both renter's and auto. It is worth a call